# What tense should I use here? Present perfect/past simple

Tags: british-english, tenses

It's been two years since the accident and she (forgot or has forgotten?) her lesson.

Comment: Depends on whether _her lesson_ has anything to do with _the accident_, which is totally unclear without context. If they're time-linked events, then this is a present relevance perfect; if not, and they're independent events, past is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Has forgotten*. You're describing an ongoing condition, a condition of forgetfulness that arose at some unspecified time in the past and has continued right up to the present.